# Getting the class instances after deserialization in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create the `Userr` object from the given serialization. In Django REST Framework documentation they mentioned the save() function which have to return the instance, but that's not what's happening.

```
class Userr(object):
    def __init__(self, email, name):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name

class UserrSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Userr(**validated_data)

u_serializer = UserrSerializer(data={'email': bla.bla@ex.org', 'name': bla'})
print (u_serializer.is_valid())
user = u_serializer.save()
```

I expect the `user` variable to be initialized with an object of the class `Userr`. Instead I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/katkov/PycharmProjects/hbp-knowledge-graph/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/katkov/PycharmProjects/hbp-knowledge-graph/hbp_knowledge_graph/ontology/tests/test_dataset_json_deserializer.py", line 73, in testSerializers
    u_serializer.save()
  File "/Users/katkov/PycharmProjects/hbp-knowledge-graph/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 598, in save
    self.save_object(self.object, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/katkov/PycharmProjects/hbp-knowledge-graph/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 580, in save_object
    obj.save(**kwargs)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You're writing DRF3 code while working on DRF2 library. Make sure you have the newest DRF installed.

Comment: we're using rest_framework version 2.3, but according to the docs, you have the same `save()` method there. How to modify the code for 2.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it thanks to mariodev. I used rest_framework version 2.3 and tried to run 3.0 code on it. 
For 3.0 the class should look like that:

```
class UserrSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance:
            # Update existing instance
            instance.email = attrs.get('email', instance.email)
            instance.email = attrs.get('name', instance.name)
            return instance
        return Userr(**attrs)
```